# Hide/show results based on filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC.net web application. 
In the view I have a List of records from my database. 
The records are displayed in the following format

```
if (List!=null)
{
<table>
    <thead>
     <th></th>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
    foreach (item in List)
      if (item.startWith("AA"))
      {
      hide the item originally. and add class to be used by javascript/jquery to show/hide element
      }
    <td>Item</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

What i want to do is put a button above the table "Show/hide"
That will hide/show some of the results when clicked.
This is oversimplified skeleton of my code. My actual table has much more information on it.

Comment: **some of the results** ? Can you be more specific ? We need a pattern

Comment: I need to hide the results which are starting with a prefix. "AA". I will change the code a bit to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the items that should be shown/hidden, e.g. with a marker CSS class. You can also set the `display` CSS property to hide them initially.

```
@{ const string markerCssClass = "js-hideable"; }
<table>
    <thead>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        foreach (item in List) {
           @{  var isHideable = item.StartsWith("AA"); }
            <td class="@(isHideable ? markerCssClass : string.Empty)" 
                style="display: @(isHideable ? "none" : "block")">Item</td>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<button id="show">Show</button>
```

Then use jquery to show/hide these items using the marker class as selector.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#show').on('click', function() {
       var affectedElements = $('.@markerCssClass');
       affectedElements.show();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the filtering with pure CSS if you put the button BEFORE the table and either at the same level or higher.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #filter-toggle:checked ~ .filterable-table .filterable { display: none; }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <input id="filter-toggle" type="checkbox">
        <label for="filter-toggle"> Filter</label>
        <table class="filterable-table">
            <tr class="filterable"><td>Hide me when filtered</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Show me when filtered</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks Steve. I solved the problem using Georg approach